# TypeORM/Express router API responding 404 on POST request

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, typeorm

I'm currently stuck on a bug I'm having when trying to do POST requests to a local test endpoint.

I'm using Insomnia to send a simple `Resister` JSON POST request to `http://localhost:5000/api/auth/register` with the following:

```
{
    "email":"test@email.com",
    "username":"test",
    "password":"test"
}
```

However I get a `404` response but looking at the logs and debug the query to my database runs?
This response seems to be sent before the trycatch block. Then the server crashes because it can't send the header again if there's further errors.

the code block for the request is below:

### auth.ts

```
const register = async (
  req: Request,
  res: Response
): Promise<Response<any>> => {
  const { email, username, password } = req.body;

  try {
    // VALIDATE DATA

    let errors: any = {};

    const emailUser = await User.findOne({ email });
    const usernameUser = await User.findOne({ username });

    if (emailUser) errors.email = "sorry, email is already taken";
    if (usernameUser) errors.username = "sorry, username is already taken";

    if (Object.keys(errors).length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json(errors);
    }

    // CREATE THE USER

    const user = new User({ email, username, password });

    errors = await validate(user);
    if (errors.length > 0) {
      return res.status(400).json(mapErrors(errors));
    }
    await user.save();

    // RETURN THE USER

    return res.json(user);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return res.status(500).json(err);
  }
};

...

const router = Router();
router.post("/register", register);
```

### server.ts

```
...
import authRoutes from "./routes/auth";
...
app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
...
app.listen(PORT, async () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${PORT}`);

  try {
    await createConnection();
    console.log("Database Connected");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated, and please do let me know if you need any other code blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind - I fixed it, I had a middleware to trim whitespace out of username and email - I called the next() function inside the wrong code block.
Putting it outside of the block solved all these issues.